# Pagination won't work once its on page 2 PHP

Tags: php, pagination

So basically everything shows when it's on search.php. However, once it gets to search.php?pn=2, The table and pagination navigation disappear. Here's the code

```
<?php require('includes/header.php'); ?>
<?php

/* Array values
 * ------------
 * $_POST['search']; // the search field
 * $_POST['submitsearch']; // the search button
 * 
 */

if(isset($_POST['submitsearch'])) {
    $search = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['search'])));
    $search = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $search);
    $total_words = count($search);
    $postsearch = $_POST['search'];

    if(empty($_POST['search'])) {
        echo "Enter something to search";
    }else{
        if(strlen($_POST['search']) < 4) {
            echo "Search must be 3 or more characters long";
        }else{
           $where = "";

           foreach ($search as $key=>$searches) {
              $where .= "description like '%{$searches}%'"; 
              if($key != $total_words - 1) {
                  $where.= " and ";
              }
           }

           $results = mysql_query("select name, left(description, 100) as description, logo, userid, number_sold, price from ns_products where $where") or die(mysql_error());

           echo "<table border=1>";
           if(mysql_num_rows($results)==0) {
               echo "<tr><td>No results found for <strong>$postsearch</strong>.</td></tr>";
           }else{

           //originial query
$sql = mysql_query("select id, name, left(description, 100) as description, logo, userid, number_sold, price from ns_products where $where"); 
//end of original query


$nr = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
if (isset($_GET['pn'])) { 
    $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); 
} else {
    $pn = 1;
} 

$itemsPerPage = 3; 
$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);
if ($pn < 1) { 
    $pn = 1; 
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { 
    $pn = $lastPage; // force it to be $lastpage's value
} 
// This creates the numbers to click in between the next and back buttons
$centerPages = ""; // Initialize this variable
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;
if ($pn == 1) {
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="search.php?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="search.php?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="search.php?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="search.php?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="search.php?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="search.php?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="search.php?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="search.php?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 


$sql2 = mysql_query("select id, name, left(description, 100) as description, logo, userid, number_sold, price from ns_products where $where $limit"); 


$paginationDisplay = ""; 
if ($lastPage != "1"){
    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '<img src="images/clearImage.gif" width="48" height="1"/>';
    if ($pn != 1) {
        $previous = $pn - 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="search.php?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a>     ';
    } 
    $paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';
    if ($pn != $lastPage) {
    $nextPage = $pn + 1;
    $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="search.php?pn=' . $nextPage . '"> Next</a>     ';
    } 
}

$num_results = mysql_num_rows($results);

if($num_results == 1) {
    echo "Search has returned 1 result.";
}else{
    echo "Search has returned $num_results results.";
}

echo "<tr><td></td><td>Name</td><td>Description</td><td>Sold</td><td>Price</td><td>Owner</td></tr>";
//while loop here
while($row8 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
    $prodname = $row8['name'];
    $prodid = $row8['id'];
    $proddesc = $row8['description'];
    $prodprice = $row8['price'];
    $prodlogo = $row8['logo'];
    $prodsold = $row8['number_sold'];
    $userid = $row8['userid'];
    $prodownerquery = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from users where id='{$userid}'"));
    $prodowner = $prodownerquery['username'];

    echo "<tr><td><img src=images/productpics/$prodlogo></td><td><a href=viewproduct.php?pid=$prodid>$prodname</a></td><td width=200>$proddesc...</td><td>$prodsold</td><td>$$prodprice</td><td><a href=viewuser.php?pid=$userid>$prodowner</a></td></tr>";

        }
       }

    }
   }
}
echo "</table>";
echo $centerPages;

?>
<?php require('includes/footer.php') ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you left `<?php require('includes/footer.php') ?>` in your code example so I can diagnose the problem accurately.

Comment: Thats a lot of code to go through. Make your question *much* simpler.

Comment: Please narrow down your code snippet substantially, or this question will likely be closed as overly broad.

Answer (score 2):

For God's sake, use a framework. I haven't had a look at your code much but just at how you make query to your database, I'm sure you will end up creating exploitable code via SQL Injections (your queries aren't decoupled so you need to sanitize everytime).

Also, frameworks have paging builtin.

Here's a list for PHP (I dev in Ruby and nodejs, so there might be more)

- [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/)
- [CakePhp](http://cakephp.org/)
- [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)
- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)

Comment: Amen amen amen amen! Hell, even if he doesn't use a framework, there's plenty of existing, well-tested, drop-in classes for pagination. http://pear.php.net/package/Pager

Comment: In my case, I'm trying to learn? If I were creating a live site I would be using a framework, but shouldn't I understand the works of it before I call a function for it?

Comment: You can browse the framework code to see how it does it. You don't need to understand everything, if you want to learn, I suggest you create a web app using a framework of your choosing and experiment with it. You will gain a lot more knowledge that way